# How do I shift the contents down in the header and footer?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have tried to shift the contents in the header and footer down by using margin-bottom in all the css class but it still could not work. Please look at the image to understand what I meant. Beginner in CSS here! I have include the html and css codes below and commented in the css the places i have tried to insert margin-bottom. Thank you.

```css
   Please do help me see where I can insert margin-bottom so as my content in header and 
   footer can be shifted down a little 

 /* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */
    body{        
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .container{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto; /* Center the DIV horizontally */
        text-align: center;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .fixed-header, .fixed-footer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;        
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .fixed-header{
        top: 0;
    }
    .fixed-footer{
        bottom: 0;
    }    
    /* Some more styles to beutify this example */
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    nav a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .container p{
        line-height: 200px; /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Your Name Goes Here</title>
<style>
   
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fixed-header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">Music & Videos</a>
                <a href="#">School</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
       
    </div>    
    <div class="fixed-footer">
        <div class="container">Copyright &copy; 2021 by @travelynn</div>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To push down/up, you can use `margin`. If you are using `flexbox`, try the `align-items` property.

Comment: @AbinThaha possible to show me an example 

Comment: I have added an answer as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below snippet.

I have

- Removed unused div from your code
- Made the fixed header/footer as `display: flex;`
- Aligned it to vertical end using `align-items` property.

```css
.fixed-header, .fixed-footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;        
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.fixed-header{
    top: 0;
}

.fixed-footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

nav a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-header">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About Me</a>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#">Music & Videos</a>
    <a href="#">School</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: the question was not abou to vertically center the elements put to push the content of the header and footer down to the bottom of their container.

Comment: Yes, by using flexbox, he can do that just by changing the values of align-items.

Answer (score 0):

I've centered the content of `header` and `footer` using

```
.fixed-header .container,
.fixed-header nav,
.fixed-footer .container{
    height: 100%;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.fixed-footer .container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
/* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}


/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Center the DIV horizontally */
  text-align: center;
}


/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */

.fixed-header,
.fixed-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fixed-header {
  top: 0;
}

.fixed-footer {
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Some more styles to beutify this example */


/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container p {
  line-height: 200px;
  /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
}

.fixed-header .container,
.fixed-header nav,
.fixed-footer .container {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixed-footer .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Me</a>
      <a href="#">Gallery</a>
      <a href="#">Music & Videos</a>
      <a href="#">School</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</p>

</div>
<div class="fixed-footer">
  <div class="container">Copyright &copy; 2021 by @travelynn</div>
</div>
```

If you want it at the bottom of `header` or `footer` then you can just have to change the `align-items` property to `flex-end`

```
nav{
    ...
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.fixed-footer .container{
    ...
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```css
/* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}


/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Center the DIV horizontally */
  text-align: center;
}


/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */

.fixed-header,
.fixed-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fixed-header {
  top: 0;
}

.fixed-footer {
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Some more styles to beutify this example */


/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container p {
  line-height: 200px;
  /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
}

.fixed-header .container,
.fixed-header nav,
.fixed-footer .container {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.fixed-footer .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Me</a>
      <a href="#">Gallery</a>
      <a href="#">Music & Videos</a>
      <a href="#">School</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</p>

</div>
<div class="fixed-footer">
  <div class="container">Copyright &copy; 2021 by @travelynn</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox` in combination with `margin-top: auto`. See the comments within the CSS changes:

```css
.fixed-header,
.fixed-footer {
  display: flex; /* applies flexbox */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontally center the content */
}

.container {
  margin-top: auto; /* consumes all remaining space and as such pushed the element to the bottom */
}

/* original css */

 /* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */
    body{        
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .fixed-header, .fixed-footer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;        
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .fixed-header{
        top: 0;
    }
    .fixed-footer{
        bottom: 0;
    }    
    /* Some more styles to beutify this example */
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    nav a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .container p{
        line-height: 200px; /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Your Name Goes Here</title>
<style>
   
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fixed-header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">Music & Videos</a>
                <a href="#">School</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
       
    </div>    
    <div class="fixed-footer">
        <div class="container">Copyright &copy; 2021 by @travelynn</div>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why combination of `margin` and `flexbox`. One would make it work, right ?

Comment: @AbinThaha  spares me to use `flex-end` If content will be added that should be still displayed at the top like a site banner or logo then `flex-end` will cause issues

Answer (score -1):

i have three possible fix for this. First is by using flex-box and second method is  using grid and third is using margins

First Method Example

```
 /* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */
    body{        
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .container{
        width: 80%;

        margin: 0 auto; /* Not needed anymore*/
        text-align: center;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .fixed-header, .fixed-footer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;        
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
  
        display: flex; //makes header and footer container flex
        justify-content: center; // positions it to the center horizontally
        align-items: center; // positions it to the center vertically
    }
    .fixed-header{
        top: 0;
    }
    .fixed-footer{
        bottom: 0;
    }    
    /* Some more styles to beutify this example */
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    nav a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .container p{
        line-height: 200px; /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
        
    }
```

In the first method, you wont be needing margin: 0 auto anymore for you `.container` class. Flex-box will handle the situation.

Method 2(using grid)

```
 /* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */
    body{        
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .container{
        width: 80%;

        margin: auto; /* Center the DIV horizontally  and vertically because its now a grid item. */
        text-align: center;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .fixed-header, .fixed-footer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;        
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
  
        display: grid //set the container to grid
    }
    .fixed-header{
        top: 0;
    }
    .fixed-footer{
        bottom: 0;
    }    
    /* Some more styles to beutify this example */
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    nav a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .container p{
        line-height: 200px; /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
        
    }
```

The second method requires u to set `margin: auto` to the `.container` div to enable it center both vertically and horizontally.

Third Method is same as wat u did but this time you set your margins properly to suit your need.

```
 /* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */
    body{        
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .container{
        width: 80%;

        margin: 0 auto; /* this code already tells the container to have 0 margin from top and bottom.*/
        text-align: center;
    }
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    .fixed-header, .fixed-footer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;        
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
  
        display: flex; //makes header and footer container flex
        justify-content: center; // positions it to the center horizontally
        align-items: center; // positions it to the center vertically
    }
    .fixed-header{
        top: 0;
    }
    .fixed-footer{
        bottom: 0;
    }    
    /* Some more styles to beutify this example */
/* I have tried to put margin-bottom here but it does not work */
    nav a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .container p{
        line-height: 200px; /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
        
    }
```

To solve this third one, you need to get ride of the `0` value in your margin declaration and replace it with ur actuall measurement value. e.g `px` `em` `rem` `vw`and so on to suit your desired position.